# Rounding NSDecimalNumber HalfDown

Tags: swift, rounding, nsdecimalnumber, tax

As we all know, when calculating with a precise number (E.g. money), it's best to use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of basic `float` or `double`. Then, we have rounding options:

```
public enum RoundingMode : UInt {

    case plain // Round up on a tie
    case down // Always down == truncate
    case up // Always up
    case bankers // on a tie round so last digit is even
}
```

**Question:**

How do I perform rounding halfDown (reverse of `.plain`, round down on a tie) for this `NSDecimalNumber`?

**My original problem (you can skip this section for sure)**

Setting rounding options (can change): Up, Down, HalfUp

I'm calculating `var pT = price include tax` from a `var p = price exclude tax` by this formular:

```
pT = roundingWithOption(p * tax)
```

pT is the displaying unitPrice (must include tax <del>or business goes to jail lol</del>) and people can custom it => I have to calculate price excludes tax, by revert the process

```
p = roundingWithReverseOption(pT2 / tax)
```

Then I can save this `price exclude tax` to the server and get it back for later. We only save `p` because tax might change and we can get tax from somewhere else => pT might differ if tax changed.

The number before and after `save and continue` process should be the same if nothing change (rounding, taxes...).

It's simple when options are `.up` and `.down`, but I don't know what to do with `.plain`.

Or can you provide a better solution for calculating `priceExcludeTax` from the custom price? It'll be more complicated when applied with discount and quantity, so I just ask a simple question first.

Comment: Not clear enough for me. Are you asking for a tax calculator? If yes then its broad. Can you please come over the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: the question is just how to perform rounding `halfDown`. The other question is like an extension.

Comment: Can you please give an example of `halfDown`? `2.5 = 2.0` ?

Comment: Yes, your sample is correct. `0.5 -> 0` -- `0.4 -> 0` -- `0.6 -> 1`

Comment: If you only want to convert the value to a string, you can set up rounding directly on the `NumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this function in which `scale` define the precision wanted:

```
func roundSubPlain(_ num: NSDecimalNumber, scale: Int = 0) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    let precision = (1 / pow(10, scale + 2))
    let adjustedDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: num.decimalValue - precision)
    let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: Int16(scale), raiseOnExactness: true, raiseOnOverflow: true, raiseOnUnderflow: true, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
    let roundedNum = adjustedDecimalNumber.rounding(accordingToBehavior: handler)

    return roundedNum
}
```

So if you try with:

```
let num1 = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 5.5)
let num2 = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 6.25)
```

You will have:

```
let subNum1 = roundSubPlain(num1) // 5
let subNum2 = roundSubPlain(num1, scale: 1) // 6.2
```

If you want the same kind of work around for bankers, you coud use something like:

```
func roundOdd(_ num: NSDecimalNumber, scale: Int = 0) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    let handler = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .bankers, scale: Int16(scale), raiseOnExactness: true, raiseOnOverflow: true, raiseOnUnderflow: true, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
    let roundedNum = num.rounding(accordingToBehavior: handler)

    let diff = num.decimalValue - roundedNum.decimalValue
    let gap = (1 / pow(10, scale))

    if abs(diff / gap) == 0.5 {
        let adjust: Decimal = diff > 0 ? 1 : -1
        return NSDecimalNumber(decimal: roundedNum.decimalValue + adjust * gap)
    } else {
        return roundedNum
    }
}
```

This could be improved for sure but it works :)

```
let num = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 6.15)
let odd = roundOdd(num, scale: 1) // 6.1
```

Comment: lol best work around. very clever, thank you. Can you provide a bonus for reverse `bankers`?